# Creating a module in Magento 1.9 which is giving 404 Error

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento 1.9. I want to post hello on the page of the module I created. And I coded for it but I am getting 404 Not Found 1 error. Even though, I see my module in System>Configuration>Advanced>Advanced.
I already:

- cleared the cache manually from directory var/cache.
- disabled the cache management.
- and log out and log in.

Code:

app/code/local/Me/Two/etc/config.xml

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * @category   Me
 * @package    Me_Two
 * @author     Qurat
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
 -->
<config>
<modules>
<Me_Two>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</Me_Two>
</modules>
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <Me_Two_SomeFreeRouterName1>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Me_Two</module>
                    <frontName>me-two</frontName>
                </args>
            </Me_Two_SomeFreeRouterName1>
        </routers>
    </frontend>   
</config>
```

app/code/local/Me/Two/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
 <!-- 
/**
 * @category   Me
 * @package    Me_Two
 * @author     Qurat
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
 -->
class Me_Two_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
 
    public function indexAction()
{
        echo 'Hello developer';
    $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

public function sayHelloAction()
    {
        echo 'Hello one more time...';
    }



}
?>
```

app/etc/modules/Me_Two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * @category   Me
 * @package    Me_Two
 * @author     Qurat
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Me_Two>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Me_Two>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.